# Use the variables of the one function inside another

Tags: c++

I have two functions, as below. What I want to do is very simple. To use the variables of 
 Toh2(int dskToMv,int cLocation, int tmpLocation, int fLocation) and print them inside the Toh function like this:

```
cout<<" Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the "
    << depeg<< cLocation << "->" << fLocation <<  <<endl;
```

Here are the two functions:

```
    void ToH2(int dskToMv, int cLocation, int tmpLocation, int fLocation)
{
//function to print the numbers
     if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH2( dskToMv-1, cLocation, fLocation, tmpLocation );

  //The below print is what I want to use in the Toh2 function
 // cout << cLocation << "->" << fLocation << endl;
                    ToH2( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, cLocation, fLocation );
    }
}

void ToH(int dskToMv, string orpeg, string expeg, string depeg) 
{


    if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH( dskToMv-1, orpeg, depeg, expeg );//original peg(A),extra peg(B),destination peg(C)

    //print in this cout the two additional variables from ToH2
        cout<<" Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the " << depeg  <<endl;
        ToH(dskToMv-1, expeg, orpeg, depeg );
    }


}



       int main()
        {


   int c;
cout << "Enter the number of disks: ";
cin >> c;

ToH(c, "original peg ", "extra peg", "destination peg");

return 0;
        }
```

**Output when entering 3**:
Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg

Move one disk from the original peg to the extra peg

Move one disk from the destination peg to the extra peg

Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg

Move one disk from the extra peg to the original peg

Move one disk from the extra peg to the destination peg

Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg

**What i want to do:**

Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg 1->3

Move one disk from the original peg to the extra peg  1->2

Move one disk from the destination peg to the extra peg 3->2

Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg  1->3

Move one disk from the extra peg to the original peg 2->1

Move one disk from the extra peg to the destination peg 2->3

Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg 1->3

Comment: Make them global, or declare them in a namespace

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it ?

Comment: No don't make them global, whatever you do.

Comment: The functions seem completely unrelated. What exactly would you accomplish by doing this? Please describe the original problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have written the code to solve the Hanoi  problem. It accepts an input. Actually i have done it but instead of outputing "Move one disk from the original peg to the extra peg" i want to output "Move one disk from the original peg to the extra peg 1->2" If it prints Move one disk from the destination peg to the extra peg I want to add 3>2 at the end and so on

Comment: the functions are ready the only thing I want to  do is to use the variables of ToH2 and print them inside ToH

Comment: But, ToH2 is never called in your code above!!!! How can you access its variables if it is not even called? Also, the output you want is not correct: the second line moves from 3 to 2 which is an incorrect move

Comment: okay I fixed it, I didn't call it because I need help to do it. I want to use the variables of Toh2 inside Toh! not in main

Answer (score 3):

Your sane options are:

1. pass the local variables of the first functions to the second function. this is usually how free standing functions communicate. overload the second function if needed.
2. make an object which encapsulate the functionality of the two functions. the shared variables become member variables.

other (less suitable here) methods are lambda functions and `std::bind`.

not so sane option is to make the shared variables global one. not recommended.

Comment: can you add an example ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is impossible and doesn't make a lot of sense.

The parameters of a function only exist during a call to that function.
If you want another function to use their values, you need to have the first function call that function and pass those values to it in some way.
In particular, there's no way to find "the value that the corresponding parameter would have had if I had called a different function instead".

Combine the functions into one.

```
void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, string orpeg, int tmpLocation, string expeg, int fLocation, string depeg)
{
     if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg, tmpLocation, expeg);
        cout<<" Move one disk from the "<< orpeg << " to the " << depeg
            << " " << cLocation << " -> " << fLocation << endl;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, expeg, cLocation, orpeg, fLocation, depeg);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    cout << "Enter the number of disks: ";
    cin >> c;
    ToH(c, 1, "original peg ", 2, "extra peg", 3, "destination peg");
}
```

or, you could use a table

```
void ToH(int dskToMv, int cLocation, int tmpLocation, int fLocation)
{
    static std::string names[] = {"original peg", "extra peg", "destination peg"};
    if( dskToMv != 0 ) 
    {
        ToH( dskToMv-1, cLocation, fLocation, tmpLocation);
        cout<<" Move one disk from the "<< names[cLocation - 1] << " to the " << names[fLocation - 1]
            << " " << cLocation << "-> " << fLocation << endl;
        ToH( dskToMv-1, tmpLocation, cLocation, fLocation);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int c;
    cout << "Enter the number of disks: ";
    cin >> c;
    ToH(c, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: It's a solution to my problem, but not an answer to this question, I will upvote you but I won't mark as best answer.

Comment: okay thank you. Is that possible to add steps  count ? Like Step1 :Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg 1->3 
Step2: Move one disk from the original peg to the destination peg 1->3 Step3: ...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a namespace:

```
namespace mySpace {
       int dskToMv;
       // other variable
}
```

and access the variables from any function like this:

```
mySpace.dskToMv =20;
// .....
cout<<mySpace.dskToMv;
```

This is a general approach to share variable between function. Anyway, it seems that you implement the towers of Hanoi. Well, your code is not logically correct.

Comment: I have added the main fn